# Trouble with Iterations in Function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, integer-division

The assignment I'm working on for class is asking us to make a program that calculates integer division by means of repeated subtraction (just like multiplication is equivalent to repeated addition). So far everything works great except for the number of times that the user wants to calculate a quotient.

For some reason, the program always runs just once instead of the number of iterations/inputs that I've prompted the program to execute in the for loop.

Could I get some help with this? I'm new with functions, so I'm sure the program isn't as readable as it could be, but all I need to figure it is what is wrong with my get_num_of_inputs() function and/or num_of_inputs variable.

Thanks!! :)

```
def main():
    num_of_inputs = get_num_of_inputs()
    numerator, denominator = get_input()
    quotient = calc_quotient(num_of_inputs, numerator, denominator)
    display_output(numerator, denominator, quotient)

def get_num_of_inputs():
    return int(input("What is the number of inputs?: "))

def get_input():
    numerator = int(input("\nEnter the numerator: "))
    denominator = int(input("Enter the denominator (must not be zero): "))
    return numerator, denominator

def calc_quotient(num_of_inputs, numerator, denominator):

    if denominator == 0:
        return print("Error: invalid input")

    if numerator == 0:
        return 0

    if denominator == 1:
        return numerator

    if denominator == -1:
        return -numerator

    numerator_abs = abs(numerator)
    denominator_abs = abs(denominator)

    for iterations in range(num_of_inputs):
        #case 1
        if numerator_abs > denominator_abs:
            result = 5
            acc = numerator_abs
            quotient = 0

            while result > 0:
                acc = acc - denominator_abs
                result = acc
                quotient += 1

            if result < 0:
                return quotient - 1

            if (numerator > 0 and denominator > 0) or (numerator < 0 and denominator < 0):
                return quotient

            if numerator_abs % denominator_abs == 0 and ((numerator > 0 and denominator < 0) \
                or (numerator < 0 and denominator > 0)):
                return -quotient

            if numerator_abs % denominator_abs > 0 and ((numerator > 0 and denominator < 0) \
                or (numerator < 0 and denominator > 0)):
                return -quotient - 1
        #case 2
        if denominator_abs > numerator_abs:

            if (numerator > 0 and denominator > 0) or (numerator < 0 and denominator < 0):
                return 0

            if (numerator > 0 and denominator < 0) or (numerator < 0 and denominator > 0):
                return -1
        #case 3
        if numerator_abs == denominator_abs:

            if (numerator > 0 and denominator > 0) or (numerator < 0 and denominator < 0):
                return 1

            if (numerator > 0 and denominator < 0) or (numerator < 0 and denominator > 0):
                return -1


def display_output(numerator, denominator, quotient):
    print("\nThe quotient of", numerator, "and", denominator, "is:", quotient)

main()
```

Comment: A function can only `return` once, that will end the loop.

Comment: I think it should be `range(0,num_of_inputs)` and I think you might want to keep pepper brackets for your if conditions

Comment: Hmm.. That didn't seem to work.

Comment: @dvenkatsagar I'm not sure what pepper brackets are.

Comment: I think the problem is because you have a return in you for loop, so basically when the result becomes less than zero it will return immediately, and will not go to the next iteration. And sorry it's proper* brackets

Comment: @jonrsharpe That makes sense, but unfortunately I have to use that function as required by prompt from my teacher. Do you know of any other way to incorporate the get_num_of_inputs() function into the program without it terminating the for loop?

Comment: @dvenkatsagar No problem! Thank you for responding. Do you know of a way for it to work without a return in the for loop? Also, I thought you didn't need to use brackets in python because you just use indentation instead.

Comment: One idea is to store the value in an array for each iteration and return that at the very end and also use `continue` when you get the quotient

Comment: @dvenkatsagar We haven't really learned much about arrays yet, but I'm going to try and figure that out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is a little bit tangled up. There's no need to pass `num_of_inputs` to the `calc_quotient` function. Instead, you need to create a `for` loop that loops `num_of_inputs` times. Inside the loop you get a new numerator and denominator, call `calc_quotient`, and output the results.

In the code below I've simplified the `calc_quotient` function.

```
def calc_quotient(numerator, denominator):
    if denominator == 0:
        raise ValueError("denominator can't be zero!")

    sign = -1 if numerator * denominator < 0 else 1
    numerator = abs(numerator)
    denominator = abs(denominator)

    quotient = 0
    while numerator >= denominator:
        numerator -= denominator
        quotient += 1
    return sign * quotient

def get_num_of_inputs():
    return int(input("What is the number of inputs?: "))

def get_input():
    numerator = int(input("\nEnter the numerator: "))
    denominator = int(input("Enter the denominator (must not be zero): "))
    return numerator, denominator

def display_output(numerator, denominator, quotient):
    print("\nThe quotient of", numerator, "and", denominator, "is:", quotient)

def main():
    num_of_inputs = get_num_of_inputs()
    for i in range(num_of_inputs):
        numerator, denominator = get_input()
        quotient = calc_quotient(numerator, denominator)
        display_output(numerator, denominator, quotient)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was thinking the problem was probably in the logic of the functions.